# how to call such function $f(tx)<tf(x)$ and what properties should it have to make $\frac{tf^{\prime}(tx)}{f(tx)}\geq \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}.$

Tags: functions

I meet one continuous, differentiable and increasing function $f(x)$, whose domain is $x\geq 0$ and $f(0)\geq 0$. Moreover, $f(tx)\leq tf(x)$, $t\in(0,1)$. It is not appropriate to call it subadditive because $t \in (0,1)$, rather than a positive integer. Does anyone know how to call such a function ?

$f(x)$ is one continuous, differentiable and increasing function, whose domain is $x\geq 0$ and $f(0)\geq 0$. Does anyone know what properties should $f(x)$ have to make the following inequality hold ?$$\frac{tf^{\prime}(tx)}{f(tx)}\geq \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}, t\in (0,1).$$

Comment: the expression $\frac {f'}{f}$ is called [Logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative). That should be useful

Comment: Thanks. But the logarithmic derivative $\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}$ is decreasing with $x$ does not imply what I want.

Comment: May I know why are you interested in this equation (Obviously I am very late)?

Comment: @JohnMa Sorry even I also forget why I come across this problem. Actually many of my problems are part of some proofs I come across with.